# How to loop through a list of words and convert the vowels in uppercase and consonants in lowercase and return a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have this code but it is returning all the words in uppercase. I need also to return a pandas dataframe but I got the error

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

This is my code

```
languages = ['python', 'php', 'java', 'javascript', 'c++', 'sql']

def toggle(languages):
    new_phrase = ""
    for letter in languages:
        if letter in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] or letter in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']:
            new_phrase += letter.lower() + '\n'
        else:
            new_phrase += letter.upper() + '\n'
    return pd.DataFrame(new_phrase)

print(toggle(languages))
```

Comment: Side note: What you're calling `letters` is not the current letter of the current language, it's the current language, since you're only iterating over languages. The end result will always be a single string: `PYTHON\nPHP\nJAVA\nJAVASCRIPT\nC++\nSQL`

Answer (score 0):

### Use Pandas `apply` method

You can first create a DataFrame `df` containing a column `languages` like this.

Then use toggle function which accept a language string and do the appropriate operation on string and return the string.

Then call this function on `languages` column using `apply` method which will call it for each row in `languages` column applying the function and returning a pandas `Series` object.

This series can then be set back to the same column.

```
languages = ['python', 'php', 'java', 'javascript', 'c++', 'sql']
df = pd.DataFrame({'languages': languages})

def toggle(language):
    new_phrase = ""
    for letter in language:
        if letter in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] or letter in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']:
            new_phrase += letter.lower() 
        else:
            new_phrase += letter.upper()
    return new_phrase

df['languages'] = df['languages'].apply(toggle)
```

**Result**:

[image: New pandas Dataframe]

Comment: You can reduce the body of `toggle` function to just be `return ''.join([x.lower() if x.lower() in 'aeiou' else x.upper() for x in language])`